# Android studio File browser

Tags: java, android, xml

Does anyone know any documents or any tutorials on a simple folder browser to include in my app? What it needs to  do is

1. Tell the user to create a folder
2. Also should have an option to delete the folder.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use some libraries, [this](https://github.com/sromku/android-storage), for example.

Creating and deleting is very simple with it:

```
storage.createDirectory(path);
storage.deleteDirectory(path);
```

Comment: Hi igor_rb, thank you for responding, in my application, I don't want to use library, but to asks the user to create their own folder and also have an option to delete